# Show that the moment of a vector w.r.t. an axis doesn't depend on the point selected

Tags: vectors

I'm trying to show that the [moment of a vector](http://www.ae.msstate.edu/vlsm/non_con_force/moment/vector.htm) $\vec{v}$ with respect to an axis ($a$), doesn't depend on the point selected in that axis to perform the calculations.

First of all, let me show a sketch of the problem I did for further clarification.[image]
**Problem description**

We've got an axis ($a$) with unit vector $\hat{\omega}=\left(\omega_1,\,\omega_2,\,\omega_3\right)$, and a vector $\vec{v}$ applied over a point $P$, as the figure shows. In general, $\hat{\omega}$ and $\vec{v}$ are not coplanar (again, the vector $\vec{v}$ is not free; it is applied over a point $P$)

Let $A\in a$ and $B\in a$ be two points in the axis, $a$. I need to show that, the moment of $\vec{v}$ with respect the axis remains the same, regardless of the point ($A$ or $B$ or, in general, $Q$) used for the calculations.

**The theory**

The general procedure to compute the moment of $\vec{v}$ (applied in a point $P$) with respect to an axis with unit vector $\hat{\omega}$ is:

1. Pick a random point in $a$: $Q\left(q_1,\,q_2,\,q_3\right)\in a$.
2. Compute the moment of $\vec{v}$ with respect to that point: $\vec{M_{Q}}=\vec{QP}\times \vec{v}$.
3. Finally, project $\vec{M_{Q}}$ over the axis unit vector: $M_{axis}=\vec{M_Q}\cdot \hat{\omega}$

**What I tried**

I picked 2 arbitrary points, $A\left(a_1,\,a_2,\,a_3\right)$ and $B\left(b_1,\,b_2,\,b_3\right)$, so my job lies in proving that: $$\left(\vec{AP}\times\vec{v}\right)\cdot \hat{\omega}=\left(\vec{BP}\times\vec{v}\right)\cdot \hat{\omega}$$

I tried to use the [cancellation property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cancellation_property) to simplify the above equation, giving: $$\vec{AP}\times\vec{v} = \vec{BP}\times\vec{v}+\vec{\lambda}$$

where, obviously, $\vec{\lambda}\cdot \hat{\omega}=0$. This lets me simplify the first equation to this [triple product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product) equation: $$\boxed{\left(\vec{AP}-\vec{BP}\right)\times v\cdot \hat{\omega}=0}$$

How should I continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are very close to the answer. Note that 
$$\vec{AP}-\vec{BP}=\vec{AB}$$
So it remains to show
$$ \left(\vec{AB}\times\vec{v}\right) \cdot \hat{\omega} = 0 $$
This is true since $\vec{AB}$ lies in the same direction as $\hat{\omega}$, and then $\vec{AB}\times\vec{v}$ would be orthogonal to $\hat{\omega}$.

Comment: Oh gosh, I did all the heavy lifting but somehow overlooked your simple deduction, what a dumb I am. Thanks!